# How to use Strongloop-pm on Heroku for loopback-based nodejs applications

Tags: node.js, heroku, strongloop

I have deployed a Nodejs app (Strongloop Loopback) into a Heroku dyno following the strongloop add-on instructions.

When my process dies because of some internal application error, it does not restart. I would like to have strongloop-process manager in order to let him manage the process restarting (among many other things). It seems that the deployment in Heroku through Git (`git push heroku develop:master`) is not a deployment on the process manager (`slc deploy`).

Does Heroku actually runs PM and I am doing something wrong? Is it possible to use strongloop-pm on Heroku?

Comment: What are you doing that requires an add-on? You should be able to deploy a LoopBack app to Heroku the same way you would deploy any Node app, and Heroku should restart the app any time it crashes (within some throttling limits).

Comment: The add-on provides the installation of strongloop command line tool (slc) and strongloop controller. This last one should provide strongloop process manager built in so I can use its features. Heroky auto-restart is not enough and has wide to big wait times; strongloop process manager manages this neatly among other features I would like to heave. For what I read here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/strongloop all the devops capabilities should be provided by the add-on

Comment: At the moment those docs appear to be wrong. This sounds like a conversation you might want to have with callback@strongloop.com or on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/strongloop

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to use is the clustering and automatic restart functionality of strong-pm you can do that without the addon.

1. add strong-supervisor as a dependency of your app
2. create a `Procfile` for your app that says**:

   web: ./node_modules/.bin/sl-run server/server.js

** this should be the same as your `scripts.start` in your package.json, except with `node` replaced with `./node_modules/.bin/sl-run`